# What will be the question tag of this sentence,"Everyone of us has to cooperate, _______?"

Tags: question-tags

I think it'll be "hasn't we?". But I feel that it'll be "don't we?".

Also what is the question tag of, "Man is mortal _____?"

Will it be "isn't he?" or "aren't they?"

Comment: Depends on whether it's British or American English. I believe it's usually *haven't we* in BrE and *don't we* in AmE.

Comment: _Haven't we?_ sounds very odd  for this context in American. _Don't we?_ is fine; the _have_ of  _have to_ is a verb and not an auxiliary, so you have to use _Do_-support with questions.

Comment: The sentence is poorly constructed such that there is no idiomatic option for US English.

Comment: Mustn't we, shouldn't we, or simply the more casual "no?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contraction is messing you up.

*Everyone of us has to cooperate, have we not?*

*Man is mortal, is he not?*

*Men are mortal, are they not?*

If you use the contraction it obscures the form that works.

Answer (score 2):

Every one of us has to cooperate, capeesh?

Comment: Um, insofar as there’s any consistency across the Englishes, that’s nonstandard English. :)

Comment: Yeah, should be "don't cha know".

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrRRQZF7K_g